# Get the HTML body of a <link> element with an ID via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following in the header of my site

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="swp-google-font-headline-css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&ver=4.5.3" type="text/css" media="all">
```

I want to retrieve the full `<link>` content as shown above with jquery.

I tried

```
var a = jQuery('#swp-google-font-headline-css').get(0);
console.log(a, typeof a)
```

But the console output displayed the actual content, but it seem to be an object rather than a string and i specifically want it to be a string.

See demo https://jsfiddle.net/collizo4sky/qh6dnmg9/

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `outerHTML` property of the Element

> The [**`outerHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) attribute of the element `DOM` interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants.

```js
var a = jQuery('#swp-google-font-headline-css').get(0).outerHTML;
console.log(a,typeof a)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="swp-google-font-headline-css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&ver=4.5.3" type="text/css" media="all">ffff
```

Comment: Thats so much. Am accepting this because outerHTML seems right to me in this case than innerHTML although both gives the same result.
Mind explaining why they both output same result in my case?

Comment: @Collizo4sky, `Node.innnerHTML` will return `""empty` string as there is no HTML as child of the `link` element..

Comment: I thought when i tested with innerHTML, it worked. Apparently i was wrong. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
var a = jQuery('#swp-google-font-headline-css').clone();
console.log(a[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerHTML` property on your `a` variable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $('#swp-google-font-headline-css').get(0);
  console.log(a.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="swp-google-font-headline-css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&ver=4.5.3" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Comment: Why use innerHTML over outerHTML in this case?

Answer (score 0):

There are two means by which this can be achieved, the first – as already shown – is to use the `Node.outerHTML` property, which in your posted code can by achieved like so:

```js
var a = jQuery('#swp-google-font-headline-css').get(0).outerHTML;
console.log(a, typeof a)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="swp-google-font-headline-css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&ver=4.5.3" type="text/css" media="all">ffff
```

And the other approach is more of a shim, and achieved by appending the found-element, here the `<a>`, to another element and accessing the `innerHTML` of that parent element:

```js
function getElementHTML(node) {
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');

  wrapper.appendChild(node);

  return wrapper.innerHTML;
}


console.log($('#swp-google-font-headline-css').get(0));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="swp-google-font-headline-css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro&ver=4.5.3" type="text/css" media="all">ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use outerHTML.

`var b =  a.outerHTML;`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qh6dnmg9/2/